# Invoke Cloud Function ... from Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that I need to execute from an Angular service, which runs when a button is clicked. I've been trying to make an HTTP POST request to it and send in my data but to no avail. I've resolved all the errors it was giving me but now it just does nothing...

**HTTP Cloud Function**

```
exports.recurringPayment = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log('Cloud Function running');
    res.status(200).send('Done');
}
```

**Angular service**

```
recurringPaymentURL = 'https://recurringpaymenturl.com';
data;
newPost: Observable<any>;

constructor(public http: HttpClient){}

processPayment(user, token){

    this.data = {
    id: 123,
    userID: 23,
    title: 'Some title',
    body: 'Some body'
  }

    //Invoke https function with POST
    this.newPost = this.http.post(this.recurringPaymentURL, this.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP cloud function has a syntax error for node. The function is not closed properly.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.recurringPayment = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log('Cloud Function running');
  res.status(200).send('Done');
});
```

If you want the function to be particular to a POST request add `req.method === 'PUT'` as a condition.